# Generate Years from 1900 to current year with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a registration form with VueJS! The user has to enter his/her date of birth.

So, how can I generate years starting from 1900 to current year in `<select>` element?

I tried this:

```js
new Vue ({
  el: '.container',
  methods: {
    getCurrentYear() {
      return new Date().getFullYear();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <select id="dob">
    <option value="0">Year:</option>
    <option v-for="year in getCurrentYear()" :value="year">{{ year }}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
```

However, the year starts from 1 in this case. So, how can I loop through `<option>` with the year starting from 1900?

Comment: Why aren't you using `<input type="date">`?

Comment: @nnnnnn No, I don't want to use that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Don't use a method in the loop, use a computed property instead.
2. Don't use `v-if` in a `v-for` element. [**It's bad!**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential)

```js
new Vue ({
  el: '.container',
  computed : {
    years () {
      const year = new Date().getFullYear()
      return Array.from({length: year - 1900}, (value, index) => 1901 + index)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<select id="dob">
  <option value="0">Year:</option>
  <option v-for="year in years" :value="year">{{ year }}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking if  `v-if` was a good approach. Your answer clarifies now. Thanks a lot. Marked as answer :)

Comment: `v-if` is evaluated for each item in the array, which most of times its a waste. And computed properties are memoized so they are evaluated only once, and "updated" when some variable in it changes (reactivity). If you use a method directly inside the `v-for`, it gets evaluated every time something changes in your component, which is reeeeeeeally expensive ;)

Comment: Got it! Thanks. Choosing between `computed` and `methods` is really confusing task for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
   mounted(){
this.inittahun();          
},
     computed : {
           inittahun() {
      let years = [];
      for (var i = 2001; i <= new Date().getFullYear(); i++) {
        years.push(i );
      }

      this.years = years;
    },

    <select2 v-model="form.tahun">
              <option value="">----</option>
              <option :value="year" v-for="year in years" :key="year">
                {{ year }}
              </option>
            </select2>
```

Comment: Try to describe why your proposed solution would work for the posted problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `v-if`:

```
  <option v-for="year in getCurrentYear()" v-if="year >= 1900" :value="year">{{ year }}</option>
```

[ https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if ]