# Property or method "value" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js

I looked at one of the answers and tried to apply it, but then I realized it didn't work and I tried numerous things like using Vuex to calculate the years before I used it, but nothing worked.

[Generate Years from 1900 to current year with VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704744/generate-years-from-1900-to-current-year-with-vuejs)

Property or method "value" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Like I said, I tried using Vuex and trying to call it on the beforeCreate hook, but it didn't work.

```
<template>
          <md-field md-clearable>
                <label for="year">Year</label>
                <md-select v-model="year" name="year" id="year">
                    <md-option :v-for="value in values" value="value">
                        {{ value }}
                    </md-option>

                </md-select>
          </md-field>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Component',
  data () {
     year: null
  },
  computed: {
  values () {
      const year = new Date().getFullYear()
      return Array.from({length: year - 1900}, (value, index) => 1901 + index)
    }
  }


}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style lang="scss"  scoped>
</style>
```

I am expecting the dropdown to have years value instead of it being null and giving an error message. I also tried to rename the values, but it doesn't have to do anything with that. It's a really weird bug. I am seriously wondering if it's caused by vue.js itself.

Comment: `year` is not defined and you're using it in `v-model`

Comment: I also tried renaming it to myear, but it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah you need to define it.  in `data(){ return { myyear: null }});`

Comment: But it shouldn't even matter, because I replaced "year" to "value" to begin with.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind the previous error is that you most probably forgot to define the prop XXX in the data object of your Vue application:

```js
var application = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        // The prop XXX is not defined here, so add it ;)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data property should return values:

```
data () {
  return {
    year: null
  }
},
```

And your v-for shouldn't have **:** in front:

```
  <option v-for="value in values" >
    {{ value }}
  </option>
```

Fix those and it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your code.

First one is:

```
<md-option v-for="(val,index) in values" :key="index" :value="val">
  {{ value }}
</md-option>
```

1. You need to make the `value` attribute reactive to consider the dynamic values from the `v-for` loop.
2. Always use `:key` attribute while using `v-for`.
3. There should not be `:` as prefix of `v-for`.
4. Try to keep variable names different from the attributes for better code understanding.

Second one is:

```
data () {
  return {
    year: null
  }
},
```

You were missing to `return` in the `data()` object.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issue in your code:

1. Your are not using data properties correctly. You should return values inside data like this:

```
data () {
  return {
    year: null
  }
}
```

2. You are using a `:` before v-for which is wrong and I think that's why you are facing the issue. Just remove that `:`

Hope it helps !!